# PHP preg_split split by group 1

Tags: php, regex

I have these inputs:

```
Rosemary Hess (2018) (Germany) (all media)
Jackie H Spriggs (catering)
```

I want to split them by the first parentheses, the output i want:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "Rosemary Hess"
  1 => "(2018) (Germany) (all media)"
]

array:2 [
  0 => "Jackie H Spriggs"
  1 => "(catering)"
]
```

I tried these but not working correctly :

```php
preg_split("/(\s)\(/", 'Rosemary Hess (2018) (Germany) (all media)')
```

But it splits every space with parentheses and returns five items rather two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
$strs= ["Rosemary Hess (2018) (Germany) (all media)", "Jackie H Spriggs (catering)"];
foreach ($strs as $s){
    print_r( preg_split('~\s*(?=\([^()]*\))~', $s, 2) );
}
// => Array ( [0] => Rosemary Hess [1] => (2018) (Germany) (all media) )
// => Array ( [0] => Jackie H Spriggs [1] => (catering) )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/DNJd0). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQqyaf/1).

The [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) third `$limit` argument set to `2` makes it split the string with the first occurrence of the pattern that matches:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=\([^()]*\))` - that are followed with `(`, 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`.